# How to toggle group of buttons to show and hide?

Tags: angular, button, bootstrap-4

I have a group of buttons which also have group of buttons on each of these buttons (nested buttons).

I need only the primary buttons to show first and when clicked/toggled, will show all of its children buttons.

When the same primary button is clicked/toggled, will hide all of its children buttons.

When the other primary button is clicked/toggled, will hide the currently clicked/toggled button its children and will show all of the newly toggled button its children.

Somehow, when I clicked one of the primary buttons, all of the children buttons including other primary buttons are showing.

Currently, I have this in my *app.component.html*

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of surveyTabs">
   <button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success" 
    role="button"
    aria-pressed="true"
   (click)="buttonClicked = !buttonClicked">{{ tab.tab }}</button>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subStep of tab.step">
     <button 
      *ngIf="buttonClicked == true" 
      type="button" 
      class="btn btn-success" 
      aria-pressed="true">{{ subStep.name }}</button>
   </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
 </div>
</div>
```

This as *app.component.ts*

```
 export class AppComponent  {   
   buttonClicked: boolean = false;
   surveyTabs: any[] = [
    {
     tab: "Primary Info",
     step: [
      {name: "Introduction"},
      {name: "Body"},
      {name: "End"}
     ]
    },
    {
     tab: "Secondary Info",
     step: [
      {name: "Educational Background"},
      {name: "Work Background"}
    ]
   },
   {
     tab: "Tertiary Info",
     steps: [
      {name: "Licenses"},
      {name: "Medical Background"},
      {name: "Criminal Record"}
     ]
   }
  ]  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering 3 buttons but *all* of them are changing the same variable, `buttonClicked`. You need to create a variable for each button. There are many ways to achieve this, but this is my suggestion:

In `app.component.ts` you generate a `buttonClicked` property for each tab:

```
 export class AppComponent  {   
   surveyTabs: any[] = [
    {
     tab: "Primary Info",
     buttonClicked: false,
     step: [
      {name: "Introduction"},
      {name: "Body"},
      {name: "End"}
     ]
    },
    {
     tab: "Secondary Info",
     buttonClicked: false,
     step: [
      {name: "Educational Background"},
      {name: "Work Background"}
    ]
   },
   {
     tab: "Tertiary Info",
     buttonClicked: false,
     step: [
      {name: "Licenses"},
      {name: "Medical Background"},
      {name: "Criminal Record"}
     ]
   }
  ]  
}
```

And in the template you refer to it:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-3">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of surveyTabs">
   <button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success" 
    role="button"
    aria-pressed="true"
   (click)="tab.buttonClicked = !tab.buttonClicked">{{ tab.tab }}</button>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subStep of tab.step">
     <button 
      *ngIf="tab.buttonClicked == true" 
      type="button" 
      class="btn btn-success" 
      aria-pressed="true">{{ subStep.name }}</button>
   </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note that you have a typo in `surveyTabs` array: the last element has a property called `steps`, the other has `step`. I recommend you from now on to type your variables, this is an error Typescript is very helpful with.

Here is a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f65bxk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Error says "Property _'buttonClicked'_ does not exist on type _'AppComponent'_". I tried adding a property _'buttonClicked: boolean'_  but now the button doesn't work. It's not toggling on and off.

Comment: @newProgHere have you made the changes to the template (app.component.html) as well?

Comment: Yes I've added the _tab.buttonClicked_. I also added a variable _buttonClicked: boolean_ since error states that property doesn't exist. After adding, the button is not toggling on and off.

Comment: @newProgHere I have updated my answer. You have a typo in the last item in the array. I have also added a demo of stackblitz. Let me know!

Comment: It works now. My error is I forgot to add _*ngIf="tab.buttonClicked == true"_ for the children button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adapt it a bit, but the idea would be to use an active and togglable class css:

```
.togglable {
  display: none;
}

.togglable.active {
display : block;
}
```

you have to change the class of your button as :
`class="togglable btn btn-success"`

when you need to enable or disable it :

```
element =  document.querySelector('#togglable'); // or querySelectorAll() ... 
// enable :
element.classList.toggle("active", true);
// disable :
element.classList.toggle("active", false);
```